# Count the number of children and the children of these children

Tags: sparql

Let's suppose I have a list of grandparents each one of them having children and recursively each one of them having their own children. Like a family tree.

Let's say one of the grandparents is Aerys Targaryen.

> *Aerys Targaryen* has 3 children, Rhaegar, Viserys and Daenerys.
>
> *Rhaegar* has 1 child, John Snow.
>
> *Viserys* has 0 children.
>
> *Daenerys* has 3 children, Drogon, Rhaegal and Viserion.

I would like to make a table showing:

**1st column:** Name of the grandparent

**2nd column:** Number of children the grandparent has(1st column)

**3rd column:** Name of the children

**4th column:** Number of children the parent has (3rd column)

**5th column:** Name of the children

I would like to have a result like this:

```
+-----------------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
|     GPName      | PCount |  PName   | CCount |   CName   |
+-----------------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
| Aerys Targaryen |      3 | Rhaegar  |      1 | John Snow |
| Aerys Targaryen |      3 | Viserys  |      0 |           |
| Aerys Targaryen |      3 | Daenerys |      3 | Drogon    |
| Aerys Targaryen |      3 | Daenerys |      3 | Rhaegal   |
| Aerys Targaryen |      3 | Daenerys |      3 | Viserion  |
+-----------------+--------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

I have managed to make these queries, but none is what I want.

  1.

```
SELECT ?GPName (count(?PName) as ?number)(group_concat(?PName;separator=",") as ?PName)
WHERE
{
     ?gp rdf:type gag:GrandParent .
     ?gp gag:name ?GPName .
     ?p gag:has_parent ?gp .
     ?p rdf:type gag:Parent .
     ?p gag:name ?PName
} group by ?GPName
```

I only get the first 3 columns and not in the form that I want.

  2.

```
SELECT ?GPName 
       (count(?PName) as ?PCount)
       ?PName
       (count(?CName) as ?CCount)
WHERE
{
      ?gp rdf:type gag:GrandParent .
      ?gp gag:name ?GPName .
      ?p rdf:type gag:Parent .
      ?p gag:name ?PName.
      ?p gag:has_parent ?gp .
      ?c rdf:type gag:Child .
      ?c gag:name ?CName.
      ?c gag:has_parent ?p.
} GROUP BY ?GPName ?PName
```

It only shows columns 1,3,4 as I want them.

Comment: Not knowing your data makes it a bit difficult ...

Comment: `prefix : <http://ex.org/> 
select ?s ?cnt ?c ?ccnt ?cc {
?s a :GrandParent .
?s :child ?c .
OPTIONAL {?c :child ?cc}

{
select ?s (count(?c) as ?cnt) {
?s a :GrandParent .
?s :child ?c
} group by ?s
}

{
select ?c (count(?cc) as ?ccnt) {
?c a :Child .
optional {?c :child ?cc}
} group by ?c
}

}`

Comment: Based on this data: `@prefix : <http://ex.org/> .
:Aerys_Targaryen :child :Rhaegar, :Viserys, :Daenerys ; 
  a :GrandParent, :Parent .
:Rhaegar  :child :John_Snow ; 
  a :Parent , :Child .
:Daenerys  :child :Drogon, :Rhaegal, :Viserion ;
  a :Parent, :Child .
:Viserys a :Child .`

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to understand. Unfortunately, this is hard to apply to the actual data.

Comment: I think you don't have "grandparent" relationships expressed in your actual data -- just "parent" and "child" -- so you need some *reasoning* a/k/a *inference*. These articles are likely to help -- [Magic Sets and Custom Inference Rules in Virtuoso 8.x](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/db783f8d98d2), [Using British Royal Family Data Snippets — to demonstrate SPARQL Query Language-based Reasoning & Inference](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/56626a152419).

Comment: @ΔήμητραΓεωργίου what means "hard to apply"? I you provide your dataset, I could adapt the query. Other than that, the main idea to use sub-queries for the count queries. As I said, and as you can see in my sample data, I tried to create the data based on your query. In reality, I'd never use classes for `:Parent` and `:GrandParent` because those could be inferred by the existence of `:child` property and path `:child/:child` respectivley.

Comment: @AKSW "Grandparent" is just a name. Indeed as you both mentioned (& @TallTed) all the relationships are parent-child. The actual "Grandparent" is this [link](http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/page/ontology/%CE%A0%CE%B5%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%86%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1) Do you think I can edit the question to be more clear?

Comment: I don't see any child or parent property in your link. Again, you should just provide proper sample RDF data, otherwise it's impossible to provide you the query. At least for me, and my suggested query already explains the main principle with subqueries

Comment: OK @AKSW. Thank you again. I will try to apply the principle you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was pointed out, you need two separate subqueries to calculate the required aggregates for each of the solutions. Added an `OPTIONAL` in case there are no children for a parent and used a `coalesce` expression to set it to zero in the projection if that was the case.

E.g something along the lines of the following query 
(I've checked it against the dataset at http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag-endpoint ) :

```
PREFIX gag: <http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?gpName ?cnt ?PName (coalesce(?cc, 0) as ?cnt2) ?CName
WHERE 
{
    {
        select ?gp (count(?pe1) as ?cnt) {
            ?gp a gag:Περιφέρεια .
            ?pe1 a gag:Περιφερειακή_Ενότητα  .
            ?pe1 gag:ανήκει_σε ?gp .
        }group by ?gp 
    }
    ?gp gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?gpName .
    ?pe a gag:Περιφερειακή_Ενότητα  .
    ?pe gag:ανήκει_σε ?gp .
    ?pe gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?PName .
    optional {
        ?c rdf:type gag:Δήμος .
        ?c gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?CName.
        ?c gag:ανήκει_σε ?pe .
        {
            select ?pe (count(?c1) as ?cc) {
                ?c1 rdf:type gag:Δήμος .
                ?c1 gag:ανήκει_σε ?pe .
            } group by ?pe
        }
    }
}
```

p.s.
As an alternative to the subqueries, you may create a cartesian product for the children and grandchildren and count the distinct bindings, e.g.:

```
PREFIX gag: <http://geo.linkedopendata.gr/gag/ontology/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select ?gpName ?PName ?CName (count(distinct ?p1) as ?cnt1) (count(distinct ?c1) as ?cnt2) 
    WHERE 
    {
        ?gp a gag:Περιφέρεια .
        ?gp gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?gpName .
        ?pe gag:ανήκει_σε ?gp .
        ?pe a gag:Περιφερειακή_Ενότητα  .
        ?pe gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?PName .
        ?p1 gag:ανήκει_σε ?gp . # cartesian product with ?pe and ?p1
        ?c gag:ανήκει_σε ?pe .
        ?c gag:έχει_επίσημο_όνομα ?CName .
        ?c1 gag:ανήκει_σε ?pe . # cartesian product with ?c and ?c1

    } group by ?gpName ?PName ?CName
    order by ?gpName ?PName
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Damyan Ognyanov! This is what I was looking for!